# How to handle creating schema/tables on the fly for a multi-tenant web app

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, multi-tenant

**Problem**

I'm building a web app, where each user needs to have segregated data (due to confidentiality), but with exactly the same data structures/tables.

Looking around I think this concept is called multi-tenants? And it seems as though a good solution is 1 schema per tenant.

I think [sqlalchemy 1.1](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/migration_11.html) implemented some support for this with

```
session.connection(execution_options={
    "schema_translate_map": {"per_user": "account_one"}})
```

However this seems to assume the schema and tables are already created.

I'm not sure how many tenants I'm going to have, so I need to create the schema, and the tables within them, on the fly, when the user's account is created.

**Solution**

What I've come up with feels like a bit of a hack, which is why I'm posting here to see if there's a better solution.

To create schemas on the fly I'm using

```
if not engine.dialect.has_schema(engine, user.name):
   engine.execute(sqlalchemy.schema.CreateSchema(user.name))
```

And then directly afterwards I'm creating the tables using

```
table = TableModel()
table.__table__.schema = user.name
table.__table__.create(db.session.bind)
```

With TableModel defined as

```
class TableModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'public'}

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )

    ...
```

I'm not too sure why to inherit from Base vs db.Model - db.Model seems to automatically create the table in public, which I want to avoid.

**Bonus question**

Once the schema are created, if, down the line, I need to add tables to all the schema - what's the best way to manage that? Does flask-migrations natively handle that?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem at the moment, I am not as advanced as you are but you may find these two links helpful. 
First article describes an approach that seems to converge with yours. https://medium.com/@hamza.senhajirhazi/how-to-handle-schema-multi-tennancy-with-python-flask-sqlalchemy-postgres-7000dda10749 / 
Second article is a possible answer to your bonus question, and relates to automated migrations in Postgres, here on multiple db instead of schemas: https://benchling.engineering/move-fast-and-migrate-things-how-we-automated-migrations-in-postgres-d60aba0fc3d4

Comment: I don't that medium article describes how to create the tables dynamically, they create the tables with a sql editor, although I didn't know about before_request, which seems like it's going to be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: A question... Using different schemas is useful in a tenant model with differentiated functions for different tenants. If you say that the data are going to be exactly the same, why not use RLS instead? It is a much easier process conceptually and operationally.

Comment: @grommit I didn't know about RLS to be honest - I'll look into it.

It just feels like having stuff in the same table makes it less secure? But I guess that's not necessarily true if it's implemented corerctly.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone sees this in the future, this solution seems to broadly work, however I've recently run into a problem.

This line

```
table.__table__.schema = user.name
```

seems to create some odd behaviour where the value of user.name seems to persist in order areas of the app, so if you switch user, the table from the previous user is incorrectly queried.

I'm not totally sure why this happens, and still investigating how to fix it.